# CS50 pset4 filter blur function

Tags: c, cs50, blur

I wrote a code for the blur function, but it returns a wrong output for reason which is not known for me (it just looks fine for me), here is an example (always same):

```
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
    expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"
:) blur correctly filters pixel on edge
:) blur correctly filters pixel in corner
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
    expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "70 85 95\n80 9..."
```

and the code is here:

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE original[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            original[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                }
                else if (j == width - 1)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                }
            }
            else if (i > 0 && i < height - 1)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i- 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                }
                else if (j == width - 1)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i- 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                }
                else
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed) / 9);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen+ original[i + 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen) / 9);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i + 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue) / 9);
                }
            }
            else if (i == height - 1)
            {
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                }
                else if (j == width - 1)
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen) / 4);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue) / 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtGreen = round((original[i][j].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j].rgbtGreen + original[i][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtGreen + original[i][j + 1].rgbtGreen + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtGreen) / 6);
                    image[i][j].rgbtBlue = round((original[i][j].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j].rgbtBlue + original[i][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j - 1].rgbtBlue + original[i][j + 1].rgbtBlue + original[i - 1][j + 1].rgbtBlue) / 6);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if the members of the structure `RGBTRIPLE` has integer types, *integer division* happens in the lines like

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = round((original[i][j].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j].rgbtRed + original[i][j + 1].rgbtRed + original[i + 1][j + 1].rgbtRed) / 4);
```

and the results are truncated to integers before passed to the `round()` function.

The dividers should be floating-point numbers like `4.0` instead of integers like `4`.

If the judge still rejects your answer after applying this change, it should be due to the calculation errors in floating-point numbers. In this case, you should avoid using floating-point number calculation and think how to calculate the desired values using only calculation in integers.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is much short I guess

```
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
//Iterates through all the pixels

for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < width; j++)
    {

        //Stores average of all the pixels around the certain color

        int avgrgb[3] = {0,0,0}, n = 0;

        // Matrix “a” and “b” represent the nine pixels address around the pixel of address i and j  
 
        int a[3][3] = { {i-1, i-1, i-1}, {i, i, i}, {i+1, i+1,i+1} }, b[3][3] = { {j-1, j, j+1}, {j-1, j, j+1}, {j-1, j, j+1} };

        //Iterating through the pixels around the middle pixel           

        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
            {

                // Checking if the index contains any negative integer(negative integer represents a pixel outside the image for corner or edge pixel)

                if (a[x][y] >= 0 && a[x][y] >= 0)
                {

                    // Calculates the sum of the valid pixel colours 

                    avgrgb[0] += image[a[x][y]][b[x][y]].rgbtRed;
                    avgrgb[1] += image[a[x][y]][b[x][y]].rgbtGreen;
                    avgrgb[2] += image[a[x][y]][b[x][y]].rgbtBlue;
                    n++;
                }
            }
        }

        // Calculates the actual average    

        avgrgb[0] /= n;
        avgrgb[1] /= n;
        avgrgb[2] /= n;

        // Assigning new pixel values

        image[i][j].rgbtRed = avgrgb[0];
        image[i][j].rgbtGreen = avgrgb[1];
        image[i][j].rgbtBlue = avgrgb[2];
    }
}
return;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your suggestion is considered, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MikeCAT's answer is surely right. Just as an alternative to his suggestion, you could avoid the conversions to and from floating point by adding half the divisor before the integer division, e. g.

```
image[i][j].rgbtRed = (original[i][j].rgbtRed + … + original[i+1][j+1].rgbtRed + 2) / 4;
…
image[i][j].rgbtRed = (original[i][j].rgbtRed + … + original[i-1][j  ].rgbtRed + 4) / 9;
```